# How to use Named Cells in XlsxWriter

Tags: xlsxwriter

The example at https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#define_name does not appear to be valid anymore:

```py
workbook.define_name('Exchange_rate', '=0.96')
worksheet.write('B3', '=B2*Exchange_rate')
```

The code appears to have been changed to define_names.append, but its unclear how to use it.

Is it just me, or is the example now out of date?

How do you read and set a named range?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it just me, or is the example now out of date?

The example is still valid. The code snippet is taken from this larger [example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_defined_name.html) and running that gives the expected output:

[image]

> How do you read and set a named range?

You can set a named range, as shown in the linked example. You cannot read it with XlsxWriter.